# Equation labels in the block environment of beamer class are too close to the right boder

Tags: beamer, environments, indentation

I am using bearmer to write a poster. In the block environment, I have same labeled equations. The problem is the labels are too close to the block border. Is it possible to move the label a little inward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beamer documentation (`beameruserguide` p. 124) suggests enclosing the body material of a block in a minipage.  Making the width `0.8\linewidth` will make this minipage narrower, preceeding it by `\centering` will center it.  So the following works well in the situation of the first example in the `beamerposter` distribution:

```
\begin{block}{Introduction}
   \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item some items and $\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$
       \item some items
       \item some items
       \item some items
       \end{itemize}
       \begin{equation}\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}\end{equation}
     \end{minipage}
  \end{block}
```

Comment: Dear Andrew Swann, thank you very much for your advice! :-)